# Is express Body parser Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am creating RESTful API for my application, and I am using Bodyparser for parsing the JSON  data sent to my API endpoint.

```
app.get('/api/endpoint', function(req,res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.body.path.split('/'));
   res.status(200).end();
});
```

I had configured the bodyparser in below way,

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The problem is when I send this,

```
var params = {
            path: '/dir1/dir2/dir3/pptdir'
        };
```

It throws an error, 
**TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined**

After this error both the console.log statements work fine and prints the below output.

```
{ 
  path: '/dir1/dir2/dir3/pptdir'
}

[ '', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'pptdir' ]
```

Comment: What throws that error? The code you've shown us works as you've already stated. P.S. The body parser is not asynchronous.

Comment: How do you "send" this? What you've shown is an object literal, not a http request.

Comment: @Bergi I sent those params in "supertest" send() method.

Comment: @freakish: is it working really ? Why not working for me, I posted the same code, no change.

Comment: @kamalakannan-PE: By "working" he means that you successfully get the logs that you expected. So that's why we need to see the stacktrace of the exception, please

Comment: Actually, it is not an exception, the Node.js server stops because of that TypoError.